# How to select <a> tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In this way, I was trying to select the a tag but it has not been selected. How can I do this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function($) {
        var test = $('.page_item').find('> a').text();
        alert(test);



      })(jQuery)
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <li class="page_item page-item-24">
      <a href="http://localhost/techblog/contac-us/">Contac us</a>
    </li>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: What errors ado you get in your console?

Comment: not any errors. actually, it has not been selected. I got an empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it easier for yourself by adding an ID to the `a` element:

```
<a id="js-contact-us" href="http://localhost/techblog/contac-us/">Contac us</a>
```

Then:

```
$('#js-contact-us').text()
```

### EDIT

Note: Your code as written WORKS. (However inelegant it might be.)

Are you sure it's only executing once the DOM is ready (the HTML has been parsed?). If you run it as it is in your example, the script will run before the HTML is loaded.

Move the script tag to before the closing body tag, or add `defer`, or wrap it in the `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    $('#js-contact-us').text()
});
```

Comment: will not add any id. I am trying to select it without an id and class

Comment: @saikatmondal This is clearly only part of the source code. Without seeing the whole code, it's impossible to know how things might interfere with the selector.

Comment: actually, this structure comes from the WordPress backend. so I am trying to add a class to a tag. but I am noticed that a tag not selected.
html structure will not change. so please help me select the a tag.
if I can select the a tag my problem will will be finish

Comment: @saikatmondal As I say, it's impossible to write a perfect selector for you because `page_item` and  `page-item-24` are probably going to be reused elsewhere on the page, possibly with `<a>` elements within them. Just make sure the page has finished rendering before running your little script: One solution is to fix this is add `defer` to the `<script>` element, or another is to move it to just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: I could find my problem myself. I should write to the scripts above the closing body tag. I was writing the script in the head tag. thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add this to the selector, istead of using find?

```
$('.page_item > a').text()
```

Also it would be as following with find method:

```
$('.page_item').find('a').text();
```

Comment: I have tried but not working

Comment: I could find my problem myself. I should write to the scripts above the closing body tag. I was writing the script in the head tag. thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

the script should be after elements , your html should look like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
        <!-- meta tags and title -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <li class="page_item page-item-24">
      <a href="http://localhost/techblog/contac-us/">Contac us</a>
    </li>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function($) {
        var test = $('.page_item > a').text();
        alert(test);

      })(jQuery)
    </script>

  </body>

  </html>
```